# How can I Run Excel Files as a task or job?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is it possible to schedule an Excel file to run on a certain day?

I have a file I built that is refreshed from data. I use a cell as the parameter to populate the data feed. I want to see if there is a way to setup a job to run these automatically and save them. If possible save them by a cell in Excel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you set up a scheduled task (Windows) or a cron job (Unix) for this task?

Answer (score 6):

Use the Windows Scheduler to schedule a task to open up the Excel file. You should then be able to use the Workbook_Open Event to do what you need with the file.

Answer (score 4):

As Danny and Adil B have pointed out you can use Windows Scheduler to schedule events. But I normally schedule the running of a vbs script to manipulate Excel, rather than open Excel directly - this method provides more control over macro security settings if this is an issue

See [this example](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html) for scheduling a vbs with Windows Scheduler

How is your data feed run and do you need assistance with this part?

Comment: No I have the data feed built.  What happens is I have two sheets which are populated by 2 different data feeds. these feeds have a parameter which I have done with a drop down.  Currently I go in choose the ID (parameter) click my button that refreshes the data.  Wait save as then go to the next feed and do the process is over until I have run them all.  I really would like to make this automated.