# how to automatically run a macro at a given hour

Tags: vba, timer, automation

I'm wondering if anyone here has experience with setting up a macro to run automatically at a given time... lets say 5AM.

There are some posts on mr excel but most of what I find is simply OnTime "x time" based code, and I'm unsure how this executes.

Do you have to open the sheet, run the macro and then expect it to run at the given time? Once it is open, will it run every day at that time or can you run it whenever?

Answer (score 3):

You could

1] have Windows task scheduler open your workbook.  Please see: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task

2] and then create a function in your macro that launches your code when the book is opened. See http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/6122-run-macro-open.html for more info.

Comment: thanks for the help guys... only thing is I realized that this is not going to work for me bc i am loading data into the sheet from an external data source. Whenever I open the sheet I get the message "This workbook contains links to other data sources... yada yada yada." When this message is open, Bloomberg does not load the data I need to run my macro. Is there any way to disable this message so it never appears when I open the file?

Comment: It seems this problem has an easy fix.  Please see [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/how-to-disable-the-microsoft-excel-2010-message/60daa660-a26a-4120-a9aa-e60b4633ed51)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want:

[How can I Run Excel Files as a task or job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189573/how-can-i-run-excel-files-as-a-task-or-job)

> Use the Windows Scheduler to schedule a task to open up the Excel file. You should then be able to use the Workbook_Open Event to do what you need with the file.

Comment: thanks for the help guys... only thing is I realized that this is not going to work for me bc i am loading data into the sheet from an external data source. Whenever I open the sheet I get the message "This workbook contains links to other data sources... yada yada yada." When this message is open, Bloomberg does not load the data I need to run my macro. Is there any way to disable this message so it never appears when I open the file?